# How to get param value in const funcion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Below is my code.

What I'm wondering is how to pass the data of the return parameter in the arrow function 'response' when passing the parameter to the variable 'ok'.

```
const response = (statusCode, formatter = null) => {
    const hasFormatter = typeof formatter === 'function';
    const format = hasFormatter ? formatter : _ => _;

    return (data = null) => {
        const response = {
            statusCode: statusCode
        };

        // Why is the data delivered??
        if (data) {
            response.body = format(data);
        }

        return response;
    }
};

const ok = response(200, JSON.stringify);

// Here, I put the parameter value({foo: 'bar'}) in the variable 'ok'.
console.log( ok({foo: 'bar'}) );
// {statusCode: 200, body: "{"foo":"bar"}"}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. *"Why is the data delivered??"* Because you're calling that function and passing in an argument for the `data` parameter.

Comment: Your code is working correctly. What is your desired outcome?

Comment: What is the value of `Console.log(ok)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder First, I apologize for my poor English skills. you are correct. 
The function called reponse appears to have only two parameter values. Therefore, I thought that the parameter value named "data" in the return parameter can not be imported anywhere inside the "reponse" function, but it is not.

Comment: @Bosco just return '[Function]'

Comment: @YongQuan I know that code is not a problem. I just do not know why the parameter named 'data' is passed in the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you clarified:

> The function called reponse appears to have only two parameter values. Therefore, I thought that the parameter value named "data" in the return parameter can not be imported anywhere inside the "reponse" function, but it is not.

I see the source of your confusion. You're not calling `response` at the point you're getting `data`, you're calling the function it **returns**.

Here you're calling `response` and passing it arguments for both of its parameters:

```
const ok = response(200, JSON.stringify);
```

`response` returns a function, which you're remembering in the variable `ok`. The function `ok`, when called, uses the parameters you passed `response` and also its *own* parameter, `data`. (More on how it can use `response`'s parameters in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and [a dated post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) on my anemic little blog.)

So when you do this:

```
ok({foo: 'bar'})
```

you're calling the function `response` returned, passing in an argument for the function's `data` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the exact explanation. I understood very well.